It will not last
(This is a true story)
My wife saw this last week on a walk.
When she described it, I was amazed.
I had to see the photo to believe it.
In retrospect, it makes sense
And this may be too easy,
But I cannot get the image out of my head.
What was it?

One of Six,
Tiny and branching,
Has met One of Eight,
Thin and unbranching,
Both, fragile and ephemeral.
They have joined in unison,
But it will not last.


I think your wife witnessed...

 ...a snowflake perfectly caught on a single strand of a spider's web.

One of Six,
Tiny and branching,

 'One of Six' is a snowflake, it typically having six points due to its hexagonal structure.

Has met One of Eight,
Thin and unbranching,

 'One of Eight' is something produced by an eight-legged creature, i.e a spider. It being thin and unbranching means this is likely a single strand of a spider's web (like one might see dangling from a tree), rather than a complete web (which would have many branches).

Both, fragile and ephemeral.
They have joined in unison,
But it will not last.

 Both a snowflake and a spider's web are delicate and do not last forever ('fragile and ephemeral'). The two are temporarily joined, but either the snowflake will eventually melt or the spider's web will eventually snap, and then their union will be over...

Probability-wise...

 ...since we are currently at the turn between autumn (spider season) and winter (snow season) in the northern hemisphere, this makes this solution a genuine possibility at this time of year!


This has got to be it. Interesting that spider silk is fragile and delicate in the tiny quantities used in a spider web, yet actually crazy strong: "Quantitatively, spider silk is five times stronger than steel of the same diameter. It has been suggested that a Boeing 747 could be stopped in flight by a single pencil-width strand and spider silk is almost as strong as Kevlar, the toughest man-made polymer."

@JLee Indeed - compare the ease with which it breaks when accidentally passing through one with the difficulty of then getting it all off you!

Nice answer, I was thinking something like rot13(N yrt bs na vafrpg ragnatyrq jvgu n yrt bs n fcvqre, naq gung gurl creuncf rira jrer sylvat be ubirevat (gb rkcynva gur nznmrq cneg), but couldn't make everything make sense. +1

@Prim3numbah I also got fixated on rot13(vafrpgf) for a while, but couldn't make the 'branching' part make sense. It was only when I thought around other natural things associated with the number six that this thought finally struck me...

If this is the answer, I am very curious how the photo looks like :)

I saw the "one of six" part straight away, but couldn't see the "one of eight" part. Nice.
